# How do use Google Maps Places Autocomplete REST API in Salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning, google-map

Does anyone have any example Apex code or Salesforce Lightning JavaScript code for using the Google Maps Places Autocomplete REST API within Salesforce?

Specifically to perform a GET request to end point:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input={input}&key={api-key}`

And return the response data.

Either client-side Salesforce Lightning or Server-side Apex example code/classes would be great.

Reference

- [Google Maps API Place Autocomplete Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)

NOTE: I've included my Apex code as a potential answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Apex class returns a PlaceAutocompleteResponse object.

**Usage**

```
String input = 'Amoeba';
String types = 'address';
String components = 'country:GB';

GoogleMapsAutoCompleteAPI api = new GoogleMapsAutoCompleteAPI()
PlaceAutocompleteResponse response = api.getAutoComplete(input, types, components);
```

**Apex GoogleMapsAutoCompleteAPI Class**

```
public class GoogleMapsAutoCompleteAPI {

    // Google Maps API Place Autocomplete
    // Documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

    public PlaceAutocompleteResponse getAutoComplete(String input, String types, String components) {
        String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input='
            + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input, 'UTF-8')
            + '&components=' + components // country:uk'
            + '&types=' + types
            + '&key=' + getGoogleMapsAPIKey();

        return PlaceAutocompleteResponse.parse(makeAPICall(url));
    }

    private string makeAPICall(string url) {

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse();
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        httpRequest.setEndpoint(url);
        httpRequest.setTimeout(120000);
        httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest); 

        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200){
            return httpResponse.getBody();    
        } else {
            System.debug(httpResponse.getStatusCode());
            System.debug(httpResponse.getBody());
            throw new AuraHandledException(httpResponse.getBody());
        } 
    }

    private string getAPIKey() {
        return ''; // add api key or get from custom settings
    }
}
```

**Apex PlaceAutocompleteResponse Class**

```
public class PlaceAutocompleteResponse {

    public class Matched_substrings {
        public Integer length;
        public Integer offset;
    }

    public String status;
    public List<Predictions> predictions;

    public class Predictions {
        public String description;
        public String id;
        public List<Matched_substrings> matched_substrings;
        public String place_id;
        public String reference;
        public List<Terms> terms;
        public List<String> types;
    }

    public class Terms {
        public Integer offset;
        public String value;
    }

    public static PlaceAutocompleteResponse parse(String json) {
         return (PlaceAutocompleteResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json, PlaceAutocompleteResponse.class);
    }
}
```